# Purpose of URL .../engine/engine.php

Tags: php

I am relatively new to web-development (Python), but it happens that I have a question for PHP web-devs.

Somebody tried to access my website, built in Python, via **.../engine/engine.php** URL.

My question is: for websites built in PHP, what is usually accessible via such a URL? And what could such an access mean (e.g. could such an access be triggered by the hosting platform (which is unlikely, I assume, since the app's buildpack is Python))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your website may have been accessed by an automated script. There are automated scripts also called bots that try to find vulnerabilities in websites.

These scripts send automated requests to websites in order to get more information about how they work. Its possible that such as script sent a request for engine.php to your website even though your website is based on python

Comment: Checked with some of my connections: they agree with your answer. I mark it as the accepted one.